# How to copy formula down to last column of another row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a formula in N2 and I would like to copy it down to the last row of column A that has data in it.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub copyFormula()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, m As Long
    Set r1 = Range("N2")
    m = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set r2 = Range("N3:N" & m)
    r1.Copy r2
End Sub
```